# How to combine Google map and Place API in Android

Tags: android, google-places-api

Im facing the problem about using Google Map and Place in my project. I have tried some days to find out best solution but I'm not yet.

I want to use Goolge map and Place API. My goals is when I input restaurant location into EditText search autocomplete, google map will identify this position, and show other restaurant nearby around by marker.

So, Can I use to combine google map and place to implement and use json to manage the marker?

I know Google service database has apply for user, but there are too much marker and I can not create new and manual

I have refer this link:

```
https://mapmaker.google.com/mapmaker
```

But it's not meet demand my requirement

Thank you !

Comment: yep it is possible to combine both .... 
you have to do following... 1) Create another fragment which is called from map fragment ... Implement places api there then bundle lat long and send back to map fragment... !

Comment: I'll share the code ... i have implemented it ... But you have to integrate with your project according to your requirement.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Code is bit lengthy but not difficult to imlement**

- From Map Fragment initiate places fragment .....

  ```
   Fragment fragmentObject = new AutoCompletePlacesFragment();
   Bundle args = new Bundle(2);
   args.putInt("userID", preferedUserId);
   args.putString("passengerGcm", preferedPassengerGcm);
   fragmentObject.setArguments(args);
   android.support.v4.app.FragmentManager fm = getFragmentManager();
   fm.beginTransaction()
                  .replace(R.id.container, fragmentObject)
                  .commit();
  ```

  Here is placefragment named as AutoCompletePlacesFragment.java (manage your stuff  where you find this line * //Do the things here on Click.....*)

  public class AutoCompletePlacesFragment extends Fragment implements GoogleApiClient.ConnectionCallbacks, GoogleApiClient.OnConnectionFailedListener, View.OnClickListener {

  private static final LatLngBounds BOUND = new LatLngBounds( new LatLng(-0, 0), new LatLng(0, 0));

  private EditText mAutocompleteView; private RecyclerView mRecyclerView; private LinearLayoutManager mLinearLayoutManager; 
    private PlacesAutoCompleteAdapter mAutoCompleteAdapter; ImageView delete;       GoogleApiClient mGoogleApiClient;

View RootView;

int preferedUserId; String preferedPassengerGcm; PreferenceData preferenceData;

public AutoCompletePlacesFragment() { // Required empty public constructor }

@Override public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) { }

@Override public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) { // Inflate the layout for this fragment buildGoogleApiClient(); RootView =inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_auto_complete_places, container, false);

```
    mAutocompleteView = (EditText) RootView.findViewById(R.id.autocomplete_places);
    mAutocompleteView.setOnClickListener(this);
    delete=(ImageView) RootView.findViewById(R.id.cross);

    mAutoCompleteAdapter =  new PlacesAutoCompleteAdapter(RootView.getContext(), R.layout.searchview_adapter,
            mGoogleApiClient, BOUND, null);

    mRecyclerView=(RecyclerView) RootView.findViewById(R.id.recyclerView);
    mLinearLayoutManager=new LinearLayoutManager(RootView.getContext());
    mRecyclerView.setLayoutManager(mLinearLayoutManager);
    mRecyclerView.setAdapter(mAutoCompleteAdapter);
    delete.setOnClickListener(this);
    mAutocompleteView.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {

        public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before,
                                  int count) {
            if (!s.toString().equals("") && mGoogleApiClient.isConnected()) {
                mAutoCompleteAdapter.getFilter().filter(s.toString());
            } else if (!mGoogleApiClient.isConnected()) {
                Toast.makeText(RootView.getContext(), getResources().getString(R.string.internet_error), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
               // Log.e(Constants.PlacesTag,getResources().getString(R.string.internet_error));
            }

        }

        public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count,
                                      int after) {

        }

        public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {

        }
    });
    mRecyclerView.addOnItemTouchListener(
            new AutoCompleteItemClickListener(this, new AutoCompleteItemClickListener.OnItemClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onItemClick(View view, int position) {
                    final PlacesAutoCompleteAdapter.PlaceAutocomplete item = mAutoCompleteAdapter.getItem(position);
                    final String placeId = String.valueOf(item.placeId);
                    Log.i("TAG", "Autocomplete item selected: " + item.description);
                    /*
                         Issue a request to the Places Geo Data API to retrieve a Place object with additional details about the place.
                     */

                    PendingResult<PlaceBuffer> placeResult = Places.GeoDataApi
                            .getPlaceById(mGoogleApiClient, placeId);
                    placeResult.setResultCallback(new ResultCallback<PlaceBuffer>() {
                        @Override
                        public void onResult(PlaceBuffer places) {
                            if (!places.getStatus().isSuccess()) {
                                // Request did not complete successfully
                                places.release();
                                return;
                            }
                            if (places.getCount() == 1) {
                                //Do the things here on Click.....
                                Toast.makeText(RootView.getContext(), String.valueOf(places.get(0).getLatLng()), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                                Fragment fragmentObject = new PassengerFragmentMap();
                                Bundle args = new Bundle(5);
                                     args.putString("destination",item.description.toString());
                                args.putDouble("destLat", places.get(0).getLatLng().latitude);
                                args.putDouble("destLong",places.get(0).getLatLng().longitude);
                                fragmentObject.setArguments(args);
                                preferenceData.setCurrentCabRequestDestinationPreferences(item.description.toString());
                                android.support.v4.app.FragmentManager fm = getFragmentManager();
                                if(fm!=null) {
                                    fm.beginTransaction()
                                            .replace(R.id.container, fragmentObject)
                                            .commit();
                                }
                            } else {
                                Toast.makeText(RootView.getContext(), getResources().getString(R.string.internet_error), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                            }

                        }
                    });
                    Log.i("TAG", "Clicked: " + item.description);
                    Log.i("TAG", "Called getPlaceById to get Place details for " + item.placeId);
                }
            })
    );

    return RootView;

}

// TODO: Rename method, update argument and hook method into UI event
public void onButtonPressed(Uri uri) {

}

@Override
public void onAttach(Context context) {
    super.onAttach(context);
}

@Override
public void onDetach() {
    super.onDetach();

}

public interface OnFragmentInteractionListener {
    // TODO: Update argument type and name
    void onFragmentInteraction(Uri uri);
}

protected synchronized void buildGoogleApiClient() {
    mGoogleApiClient = new GoogleApiClient.Builder(getActivity())
            .addConnectionCallbacks(this)
            .addOnConnectionFailedListener(this)
            .addApi(LocationServices.API)
            .addApi(Places.GEO_DATA_API)
            .build();
}

@Override
public void onConnected(Bundle bundle) {
    Log.v("Google API Callback", "Connection Done");
}

@Override
public void onConnectionSuspended(int i) {
    Log.v("Google API Callback", "Connection Suspended");
    Log.v("Code", String.valueOf(i));
}

@Override
public void onConnectionFailed(ConnectionResult connectionResult) {
    Log.v("Google API Callback","Connection Failed");
    Log.v("Error Code", String.valueOf(connectionResult.getErrorCode()));
    Toast.makeText(getActivity(), getResources().getString(R.string.internet_error),Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
}

@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
    if(v==delete){
        mAutocompleteView.setText("");
    }
}

@Override
public void onResume() {
    super.onResume();
    if (!mGoogleApiClient.isConnected() && !mGoogleApiClient.isConnecting()){
        Log.v("Google API","Connecting");
        mGoogleApiClient.connect();
    }
}

public void onLocationSelected(){

}
```

}

Here is PlacesAutoCompleteAdapter.java (Just copy paste this No need to change)

```
public class PlacesAutoCompleteAdapter
    extends RecyclerView.Adapter<PlacesAutoCompleteAdapter.PredictionHolder> implements Filterable {

private static final String TAG = "PlacesAutoCompleteAdapter";
private ArrayList<PlaceAutocomplete> mResultList;
private GoogleApiClient mGoogleApiClient;
private LatLngBounds mBounds;
private AutocompleteFilter mPlaceFilter;

private Context mContext;
private int layout;

public PlacesAutoCompleteAdapter(Context context, int resource, GoogleApiClient googleApiClient,
                                 LatLngBounds bounds, AutocompleteFilter filter) {
    mContext = context;
    layout = resource;
    mGoogleApiClient = googleApiClient;
    mBounds = bounds;
    mPlaceFilter = filter;
}

/**
 * Sets the bounds for all subsequent queries.
 */
public void setBounds(LatLngBounds bounds) {
    mBounds = bounds;
}

/**
 * Returns the filter for the current set of autocomplete results.
 */
@Override
public Filter getFilter() {
    Filter filter = new Filter() {
        @Override
        protected FilterResults performFiltering(CharSequence constraint) {
            FilterResults results = new FilterResults();
            // Skip the autocomplete query if no constraints are given.
            if (constraint != null) {
                // Query the autocomplete API for the (constraint) search string.
                mResultList = getAutocomplete(constraint);
                if (mResultList != null) {
                    // The API successfully returned results.
                    results.values = mResultList;
                    results.count = mResultList.size();
                }
            }
            return results;
        }

        @Override
        protected void publishResults(CharSequence constraint, FilterResults results) {
            if (results != null && results.count > 0) {
                // The API returned at least one result, update the data.
                notifyDataSetChanged();
            } else {
                // The API did not return any results, invalidate the data set.
                //notifyDataSetInvalidated();
            }
        }
    };
    return filter;
}

private ArrayList<PlaceAutocomplete> getAutocomplete(CharSequence constraint) {
    if (mGoogleApiClient.isConnected()) {
        Log.i("", "Starting autocomplete query for: " + constraint);

        // Submit the query to the autocomplete API and retrieve a PendingResult that will
        // contain the results when the query completes.
        PendingResult<AutocompletePredictionBuffer> results =
                Places.GeoDataApi
                        .getAutocompletePredictions(mGoogleApiClient, constraint.toString(),
                                mBounds, mPlaceFilter);

        // This method should have been called off the main UI thread. Block and wait for at most 60s
        // for a result from the API.
        AutocompletePredictionBuffer autocompletePredictions = results
                .await(60, TimeUnit.SECONDS);

        // Confirm that the query completed successfully, otherwise return null
        final Status status = autocompletePredictions.getStatus();
        if (!status.isSuccess()) {
            Toast.makeText(mContext, "Error contacting API: " + status.toString(),
                    Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            Log.e("", "Error getting autocomplete prediction API call: " + status.toString());
            autocompletePredictions.release();
            return null;
        }

        Log.i("", "Query completed. Received " + autocompletePredictions.getCount()
                + " predictions.");

        // Copy the results into our own data structure, because we can't hold onto the buffer.
        // AutocompletePrediction objects encapsulate the API response (place ID and description).

        Iterator<AutocompletePrediction> iterator = autocompletePredictions.iterator();
        ArrayList resultList = new ArrayList<>(autocompletePredictions.getCount());
        while (iterator.hasNext()) {
            AutocompletePrediction prediction = iterator.next();
            // Get the details of this prediction and copy it into a new PlaceAutocomplete object.
            resultList.add(new PlaceAutocomplete(prediction.getPlaceId(),
                    prediction.getDescription()));
        }

        // Release the buffer now that all data has been copied.
        autocompletePredictions.release();

        return resultList;
    }
    Log.e("", "Google API client is not connected for autocomplete query.");
    return null;
}

@Override
public PredictionHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup viewGroup, int i) {
    LayoutInflater layoutInflater = (LayoutInflater) mContext.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    View convertView = layoutInflater.inflate(layout, viewGroup, false);
    PredictionHolder mPredictionHolder = new PredictionHolder(convertView);
    return mPredictionHolder;
}

@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(PredictionHolder mPredictionHolder, final int i) {
    mPredictionHolder.mPrediction.setText(mResultList.get(i).description);
    /*mPredictionHolder.mRow.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            mGetLatLonCallback.getLocation(resultList.get(i).toString());
        }
    });*/
}

@Override
public int getItemCount() {
    if(mResultList != null)
        return mResultList.size();
    else
        return 0;
}

public PlaceAutocomplete getItem(int position) {
    return mResultList.get(position);
}

public class PredictionHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
    private TextView mPrediction;
    private RelativeLayout mRow;
    public PredictionHolder(View itemView) {

        super(itemView);
        mPrediction = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.address);
        mRow=(RelativeLayout)itemView.findViewById(R.id.predictedRow);
    }

}

/**
 * Holder for Places Geo Data Autocomplete API results.
 */
public class PlaceAutocomplete {

    public CharSequence placeId;
    public CharSequence description;

    PlaceAutocomplete(CharSequence placeId, CharSequence description) {
        this.placeId = placeId;
        this.description = description;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return description.toString();
    }
}
```

}

Here is AutoCompleteItemClickListener.java (Just copy paste this No need to change)

```
public class AutoCompleteItemClickListener implements RecyclerView.OnItemTouchListener {
private OnItemClickListener mListener;

public interface OnItemClickListener {
    public void onItemClick(View view, int position);
}

GestureDetector mGestureDetector;

public AutoCompleteItemClickListener(AutoCompletePlacesFragment context, OnItemClickListener listener) {
    mListener = listener;
    mGestureDetector = new GestureDetector(context.getActivity(), new GestureDetector.SimpleOnGestureListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onSingleTapUp(MotionEvent e) {
            return true;
        }
    });
}

@Override
public boolean onInterceptTouchEvent(RecyclerView view, MotionEvent e) {
    View childView = view.findChildViewUnder(e.getX(), e.getY());
    if (childView != null && mListener != null && mGestureDetector.onTouchEvent(e)) {
        mListener.onItemClick(childView, view.getChildLayoutPosition(childView));
        return true;
    }
    return false;
}

@Override
public void onTouchEvent(RecyclerView view, MotionEvent motionEvent) { }

@Override
public void onRequestDisallowInterceptTouchEvent(boolean disallowIntercept) {

}
```

}